# Woocommerce change default product images to their category image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So, here is the woocommerce setting that I have.

I have a few categores, let’s call them A, B, C, D, E… and so on.

From the backend, I gave category images to each categories.

Now, let’s say I post a product in the category A without selecting any images.

The product just shows the woocommerce default image (the one with the grey background).

Is there a way to use the category images as the default product image when there is no image selected?

I have tried a few codes, this is the last one I have:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_fix_thumbnail');

function custom_fix_thumbnail(){

    add_filter('wc_placeholder_img_src', 'custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src');

    function custom_woocommerce_placeholder_img_src( $src ) {
        if (is_shop() || is_singular('product') || is_archive() || is_checkout() || is_cart()) {
            global $post;
            $array = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
            reset($array);
            $first_key = key($array);
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($first_key, 'thumbnail_id', true);

            // get the image URL for parent category
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);

            // print the IMG HTML for parent category
            if ($image)
                $src = $image;

        }
        return $src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I am desperate for a way to do this a well.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing hook to `woocommerce_placeholder_img_src`. `wc_placeholder_img_src` seems to be deprecated.